# Can't figure out why array length is undefined

Tags: reactjs, axios

I keep receiving the following message in my console, "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

quotesData.quotes should be the key for an array, however, so I'm unsure as to why its length property is undefined.

quotesData should be a JSON object that looks like: { "quotes": [Object1, Object2, ...etc.]}

Is there something wrong with how I'm using axios? I'm still very new to programming in general and quite new to react.js

```
getQuote() {
    let _this = this;
    _this.serverRequest =
        axios
        .get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwgillette/quotes/master/library")
        .then(function(quotesData) { 
            console.log(quotesData);
            let newQuote = quotesData.quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotesData.quotes.length)];
            _this.setState({
                quote: newQuote.quote,
                author: newQuote.author
            });
        })
}
```

Comment: what does this print out  console.log(quotesData); ?

Comment: @jsdeveloper it prints the JSON object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the data you want is actually going to be on a `.data` attribute of the response. So if you fix your code up like this you will be good to go :)

```
getQuote() {
    let _this = this;
    _this.serverRequest =
        axios
        .get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwgillette/quotes/master/library")
        .then(function(q) { 
            quotesData = q.data;
            console.log(quotesData);
            let newQuote = quotesData.quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotesData.quotes.length)];
            _this.setState({
                quote: newQuote.quote,
                author: newQuote.author
            });
        })
}
```

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Because the promise resolves to response object. Try doing:

```
getQuote() {
let _this = this;
_this.serverRequest =
    axios
    .get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwgillette/quotes/master/library")
    .then(function(response) { 
        let newQuote = response.data.quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * response.data.quotes.length)];
        _this.setState({
            quote: newQuote.quote,
            author: newQuote.author
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: Ah I see it's the `.data` I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a screenshot of the response object you are getting back.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qF5I.png)

I refactored your code to work. you need to use res.data.

```
getQuote = () => {axios.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwgillette/quotes/master/library")
.then(res => {
  let newQuote =
    res.data.quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * res.data.quotes.length)];

  this.setState({
    quote: newQuote.quote,
    author: newQuote.author
  });
});
};
```

Comment: if you look at my link you will understand the exact promise you are receiving. When you make an api call you are getting more than just the data you ask for.